# Jmx_exporter kafka config example question

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx-exporter

Im looking at the example config for kafka in the official jmx_exporter repo

https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/blob/master/example_configs/kafka-2_0_0.yml

as well as the one from Kafka

https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/blob/master/charts/cp-kafka/templates/jmx-configmap.yaml

We can see things like

```
- pattern : kafka.server<type=ReplicaManager, name=(.+)><>(Value|OneMinuteRate)
  name: "cp_kafka_server_replicamanager_$1"
- pattern : kafka.controller<type=KafkaController, name=(.+)><>Value
  name: "cp_kafka_controller_kafkacontroller_$1"
- pattern : kafka.server<type=BrokerTopicMetrics, name=(.+)><>OneMinuteRate
  name: "cp_kafka_server_brokertopicmetrics_$1"
```

My question concern **Value**, is it the name of an attribute that can be found on those Means identified by the following patterns `kafka.server<type=ReplicaManager, name=(.+)>`

I would imagine that **OneMinuteRate** is one. Although i could not find it in the list of metrics provided by Confluent: https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html. My guess was that, that metrics comes from an old version of kafka.

Hence, could someone let me know what **Value** is ?

Also, is there a place where i could find the official complete list of Kafka Mbeans ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These metrics exist and are valid.

`Value` is one of the attributes of the `kafka.server<type=ReplicaManager, name=(.+)>` MBean when `name` is `AtMinIsrPartitionCount` for example.

`OneMinuteRate` is also a possible attribute on some of the names, for example when `name` is `FailedIsrUpdatesPerSec`.

The best way to find all these names is to use [`jsoncole`](http://openjdk.java.net/tools/svc/jconsole/). Upon starting, attach to the Kafka process and you can explore all the MBeans and find all attributes.